# Como desabilitar botão e habilitar somente após a seleção de combos

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2.2

Tenho um botão (Transferir) e gostaria de quando ao usuário entrar na tela o mesmo fique desabilitado e somente após a seleção das combos (combo1 e combo2) o botão fique habilitado. Estou trabalhando com **JSF**.

Segue o código da tela:

```
                <div id="dv" class="ui-widget-content  ui-corner-all"
                    style="padding: 10px; margin-top: 15px;">

                    <h:panelGrid columnClasses="_230px" columns="2" cellspacing="2"
                        cellpadding="2" styleClass="table-form" id="panelGridConsulta">

                        <h:outputLabel id="filtroMarcaLabel"
                            value="#{lbl.transferir_perguntas_frequentes_programa_origem}"
                            for="filtroProgramaOrigem">
                            <span id="a3st21">*</span>: </h:outputLabel>

                        <h:selectOneMenu
                            value="#{perguntaFrequenteBean.programaOrigem.id}"
                            style="width:300px; height:21px; margin-top:3px; margin-right: 300px;"
                            id="filtroProgramaOrigem">
                            <f:selectItem id="selecione" itemLabel="Escolha o Programa"
                                itemValue="0" />
                            <f:selectItems id="itemsMar1ca"
                                value="#{perguntaFrequenteBean.programasComPerguntas}"
                                var="programa" itemValue="#{programa.id}"
                                itemLabel="#{programa.nome}" />
                        </h:selectOneMenu>


                        <h:outputLabel id="filtroMarcaLabel1"
                            value="#{lbl.transferir_perguntas_frequentes_programa_destino}"
                            for="filtroProgramaDestino">
                            <span id="a3s234t21">*</span>: </h:outputLabel>

                        <h:selectOneMenu
                            value="#{perguntaFrequenteBean.programaDestino.id}"
                            style="width:300px; height:21px; margin-top:3px; margin-right: 300px;"
                            id="filtroProgramaDestino">
                            <f:selectItem id="seleci3one" itemLabel="Escolha o Programa"
                                itemValue="0" />
                            <f:selectItems id="item3sMar1ca"
                                value="#{perguntaFrequenteBean.programas}" var="programa"
                                itemValue="#{programa.id}" itemLabel="#{programa.nome}" />
                        </h:selectOneMenu>

                    </h:panelGrid>

                </div>

                <br />

                <h:panelGroup id="panelGroupSave" styleClass="pad-right15"
                    style="float: right;">

                    <h:outputLink value="javascript:void(0)"
                        styleClass="btn-laranja padding-left5 margem-left5"
                        onclick="doManual()" id="voltarBtn">
                        <span id="spanVoltar"><h:outputText
                                value="#{lbl.botao_transferir}" /></span>
                    </h:outputLink>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        function doManual() {
                            $("[id$='textoMensagem11110']").html(
                                    $("[id$='textoMensagem11110']").html().replace('{0}', $('#filtroProgramaOrigem').find('option:selected').text()).replace('{1}', $('#filtroProgramaDestino').find('option:selected').text()));
                            showPopup11110();
                            return false;
                        }

                        function showPopup11110() {
                            $(".dialog11110").dialog('open');
                        }

                        function closePopup11110() {
                        //$("[id$='textoMensagem11110']").html('#{msg.MN067}');
                        let texto = $("[id$='textoMensagem11110']").text();
                        string = texto.replace('- ', '');
                        $("[id$='textoMensagem11110']").html(string);                               
                            $(".dialog11110").dialog('close');
                        }

                        function executaLoad() {
                            $(".pg_load").html("&lt;div class='esmanecer'&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class='info'&gt;Aguarde...&lt;/div&gt;");
                            $(".pg_load").show();
                        }
                    </script>

                </h:panelGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer como no exemplo abaixo. Basicamente você vai utilizar o método [change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) par ver se o select foi alterado. A cada mudança no select as variáveis **retorno** recebe o valor de **`true`**, aí é só fazer um **if** para verificar se os dois selects já foram modificados, daí então habilitam o botão:

```js
$(function() {
  let select1 = $('#filtroProgramaOrigem');     // pega o primeiro select
  let select2 = $('#filtroProgramaDestino');    // pega o segundo select
  let botao = $('#voltarBtn');
  let retorno1 = false;
  let retorno2 = false;

  botao.prop('disabled', true);           // desabilita o botão no carregamento da página

  select1.on('change', function() {
    retorno1 = true;
    if (retorno2 == true) botao.prop('disabled', false);
  });
  select2.on('change', function() {
    retorno2 = true;
    if (retorno1 == true) botao.prop('disabled', false);
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="filtroProgramaOrigem">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select id="filtroProgramaDestino">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<button id="voltarBtn">Transferir</button>
```